# Update table every 15 min

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I go about updating a table with statistics every 15minutes? I've got today a structured job that updates one other table with the same statistics but on a daily basis at 8:00 and 17:00. Though now I would like to use similar logic to update it every 15 minutes. My other job is using the SQL-server agent to exec the stored procedure twice everyday. Should I just use the same logic and change the update rate to every 15 minutes in the server agent?

So this is the code for the main insert stored procedure to check and insert data and it basically cehcks the activity between 17:00 and 8:00 also the amount of different parameters at 8:00.

```
If Convert(varchar(50),DATEPART(HH,getdate())) = '8' 
begin
declare @datumstring as Varchar(30)
Declare @Datum As Datetime
set @Datum = Dateadd(dd,-1,GETDATE())
set @datumstring = convert(varchar, @Datum,102)
set @datumstring = @datumstring + ' 17:00'
set @Datum = CONVERT(datetime, @datumstring)
```

Then the insert mostly contains alot of subselects but it's not important here, although I'll post one of them so you can see how I use the date conditions.

```
(select COUNT(*) from table b 
where b.ob = 4 and b.t = 7 and Time  
between @Datum and GETDATE() and b.Name = LoginName)
```

Could I use the similar logic with time manipulation with variables or should I just make a similar insert into a table, then update that stored procedure every 15 minutes?

Cheers

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to save the statistics every 15mins for the changes that have occurred in the last 15mins (i.e. since the previous statistics were saved)?

Comment: good questions, I want to update hence not save the previous which means the data is always "fresh"

Comment: I'd be considering using one or more indexed views or (if your data requirements don't fit the limitations of them) triggers so that the data is maintained automatically whenever changes are applied to the other tables. Why pick any particular update frequency when the best one is usually "whenever the underlying data has changed"?

Comment: Yes I know thats what I've said to the customer, its the person who order this function who wants it that way. I leave my personal thoughts about it out of here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as I understand you need something which will help you to execute some particular code block in every 15 minute.

So why not try [WAITFOR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) keyword from sqlserver. Put you code in

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
     WAITFOR DELAY '00:15'
     -- CODE TO BE EXECUTE
END
```

Or can also use

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
     WAITFOR TIME '00:15'
     -- CODE TO BE EXECUTE
END
```

Comment: aaah clever! will try this:)

Comment: You should.. As I am using this, and it is very effective...
But yah If I am not wrong than you need to do some tricky things with this type of code.
In my case I put this type of SP in MASTER db and run this sp when sqlserver start.

Hope this help full to you....

Comment: Yes it's helpfull :) and thank you for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it on server use Cron Job . or if you want to do it on client site user java script . or JQuery ajex

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

see [enter link description here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)